# Looking to pull specific data from json file and and calculate results

Tags: json, vb.net, dictionary, visual-studio-2022

Hello I am working on personal project to make my job easier at work. Just to state the facts I am a novice and trying to teach myself VB.net. I have a program that I have been working on that allows me to input my time spent at the mine sites I do contract work for. My issue that I am having is that I need to pull specific information from my program and calculate the total time spent out at each mine.
[Example picture of my project with what I am trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhQcr.jpg)

My program makes the json file and it looks like so:

```
  {
    "Tdate": "4/12/2023",
    "Mine": "Cortez",
    "Tstart": "07:37 AM",
    "Tend": "09:37 AM",
    "results": "2.00"
  },
  {
    "Tdate": "4/13/2023",
    "Mine": "Cortez",
    "Tstart": "08:00 AM",
    "Tend": "09:45 AM",
    "results": "1.75"
  },
  {
    "Tdate": "4/13/2023",
    "Mine": "Phoenix",
    "Tstart": "10:30 AM",
    "Tend": "12:15 PM",
    "results": "1.75"
  }
]
```

What I need to do is pull the Mine location (in this example it is Cortez Mine) and the results of the time spent there (for this example the results of the Cortez Mines is 2.00 and 1.75), and be able to add the results together to show total time spent at each mine I go to.  I have looked all over to see how to do this and I am having a hard time finding my solution.

When I enter a new record into the program I need to be able to dynamically check the name of the mine and if it is already listed in the blue box that I have on my photo above then it just adds the results values together with what is already in the box, however, if it is not already listed in the blue box then it adds the mine name and the result to a new line in the box and so forth.

I would like the blue box to look something like so:

```
 Cortez      3.75
 Phoenix     1.75
```

and so on for each mine that I have to visit, I do not want the mine name to show up more than once in this section, I have a listview that shows all the mines that I visit and the times I have visited them through out the month. I am just trying to total out each mine as I enter them in.

All help will be appreciated, I am trying to self teach myself and I think I have done well so far in my opinion, however, I am just stuck on this final part.

I have looked all over the internet trying to find something that will help me with this, I have watched countless videos that talk about how to serialize and deserialize json files, I have not found anything on how to pull specific information and add values together

Edit to what I have done so far, but it only shows the first name is the list of mines. This is the code that I have figured out to get me this far.

```
 Public Function addnewMinelabel() As System.Windows.Forms.Label

        Dim jsonData = File.ReadAllText(GetFileName())
        Dim mineDict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of MineDetails))(jsonData)
        For Each Mine In mineDict
            Dim mineName As New System.Windows.Forms.Label
            GroupBox1.Controls.Add(mineName)
            mineName.Top = lblMineName * 27
            mineName.Left = 10
            mineName.AutoSize = True
            mineName.Text = Mine.Mine.ToString
            lblMineName = lblMineName + 1
            Return mineName
        Next

    End Function
```

This gives me the first mine in the list but does not add in any other mines that I have in the list. I am researching everything I can but need the push in the right direction to be able to add in the other mine names. Once I figure this out I will work on the results side of the program. I am attaching a picture to reference from.
[Here is the picture to Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geljh.jpg)

Comment: In VS2022 (and possibly others) you can go to the Edit menu -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON as Classes. From there it'll be back to you to serialize and build some linq to do the summary work you want. Ideally your question needs to be more specific and have code examples showing what you've tried.

Comment: You'll want to deserialize into a `List(Of T)` most likely.  Then you can use Linq functions to select from it, and `For Each ... Next` to operate on the resulting sequence.  Or you can write in something that looks more like SQL if you prefer.

Comment: I edited the original post, if anyone care help off of that. I appreciate it